# YouTube Video upload API, costs for higher quota

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Q1. Could you please assist me in obtaining an increased quota for the YouTube API specifically for the video upload API? Additionally, I would like to know the associated costs for the credits required.

Q2. Is it possible to extract an identifier from any YouTube API that indicates whether ads will be featured on a specific video or channel?

Q3. Could you please provide information regarding the free usage limit for storage and posting on a YouTube channel? Additionally, could you also detail the costs associated once the usage exceeds these limits?

we have checked the free limits in the google api console.

Comment: Q1: there are no associated costs,